# Integrated Brownian Bridge is a Gaussian Process

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Let $W(t),t \in [0,1]$ be a (Standard) Wiener Process. The Brownian Bridge $B(t), t \in [0,1]$ can be constructed via $B(t):=W(t) - t \cdot W(1)$ and is a Gaussian process with zero mean and covariance $\operatorname{ Cov} (B(s),B(t))=\min(s,t)-st$.

Now, let the **Integrated Brownian Bridge** be defined as

$\overline{B}(t):= \int \limits_{0}^{t}B(s)ds$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$.

It is stated that $\overline{B}(t), t \in [0,1]$ is a **Gaussian process** with zero mean and covariance function $$ 
\operatorname{\overline{B}(s),\overline{B}(t)} = \frac{st \cdot \min(s,t)}{2} - \frac{(\min(s,t)^{3}}{6} - \frac{s^{2}t^{2}}{4},$$ as can be seen [here](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10485250008832815?journalCode=gnst20), on page 395.

My Question(s) now: How can I show that the Integrated Brownian Bridge is a Gaussian process, i.e. how do I show the multivariate normality for any $0 \leq t_{1} \leq ... \leq t_{k} \leq 1$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$ give nthe integral expression. Do I have to do it in an "algebraic induction" fashion, i.e. starting with *simple functions*, than *non-negative ones* etc. or/and is their a kind of $L^{2}[0,1]$ formulation where I can make use of the *Cauchy criterion*.

And how to derive the covariance function? As expectations are integrals as well I guess *Fubini's theorem* is involved, right?

Thanks for any help!